# Visual Studio Code : Error 5 : An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Code version 1.31.1 running in my Windows 8.1, 64 bit machine.

Time to time it prompts me this error.

[image: Visual_Studi0_Code_Error1]

When I press "Abort" the window gets closed. 
When I press "Retry" it prompts me the same message.
When I press "Ignore" it shows me this.

[image]

Another time, when I ignore I received this message.
If you read the error message carefully, you will figure out that it is trying to create different dll file and fail to do so.

Do you have any idea why I'm getting these messages and appreciate any help to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to reinstall VSCode?

Comment: I have this problem when running the installer for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify file in C:\Program Files\ application needs to have administrator privileges. Go to installed directory, right click on Code.exe, "Properties", "Compatibility", check "Run this program as an administrator".

Comment: Yeah, don't. Regular programs (and VS Code in particular) should only ever run as admin when it is required (e.g. to debug privileged processes).

Answer (score 0):

I am solved the issue.
First of all go to the installed location Example: C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
then in this folder just simply go to properties option and security tab then add the user and Administration account to full system control. Its solved my problem.